# How can I make a reminder for tv programs?

Tags: android, notifications

Currently I am developing an Android app that displays times of TV programs for a given channel.

I want to give users the ability to determine a time to remind them before the starting time of a program.

I display all programs in a `ListView` with its times. When the user selects any item, a dialogue screen will show up and display some times (10 min, 20 min, 30 min, 1 hr).

When he choose a time from the dialogue, it will be stored in some data storage like SQLite or something else. When the time comes, it will give a notification in the notification bar.

Now how can I do that and what classes and techniques must I use?

Comment: have you tried out anything ?

Comment: no i am a beginner and i want to know what i must do or search

Comment: ListView, baseadapters, array adapters. Alarm service, internal storage to store data.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the notification period in database. As you are a beginner I'll only point you in the direction instead of proper solution. For Generating notifications use [NotificationManager](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html) and to execute some command at a certain time you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Get yourself familiar with these and you'll be good to go.

Welcome to StackOverflow, try to narrow down your question to your specific problem as the community is scarily strict.